# SQL: Trying to write code that counts the times an event occurs and then a specific event occurs after

Tags: sql, metabase

I'm working in SQL and trying to find a way to find the subsequent value (next row) and then create a count of each time the first value happens and then the second.

Something like:

OG data

| id | Sale Item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Banana |
| 3 | Apple |
| 4 | Orange |
| 5 | Apple |
| 6 | Banana |

Returning

| First Event | Second Event | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Banana | 2 |
| Banana | Apple | 1 |
| Apple | Orange | 1 |
| Orange | Apple | 1 |

I've tried to use the lead function, but it does not lead to the desired outcome.

select sale item, lead(sale item, 1) over (order by sale item) as "next sale item", count(sale item) from table
group by sale item

Comment: Please see [why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: added! sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Using *lead()* would seem to be required here, followed by a windowed count of First and Second event columns:

```
with s as (
  select *, Lead(Sale_Item) over(order by Id) Next_Item
  from OGData
)
select distinct Sale_Item First_Event, Next_Item Second_Event, 
  Count(*) over(partition by Sale_Item, Next_Item) Count
from s
where next_Item is not null;
```

Fiddle result:

[image]